# How to view or retrieve my email and password in git using .git file

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using Git ( [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) ),3 years ago my colleague programmer resign, and I can't contact them, And now I forgot what the email and password use to access to bitbucket, my only last hope is the authentication in git is save in .git files,I know its save because I can push and pull data with out inputing username and password, Its there's a way how to view git authentication.

[image]

Git File

[image]

Comment: Are you actually able to `git push` and `git pull` to the remote BitBucket repository right now?

Comment: It's very unlikely that the password is saved in plain text in .git directory. The reason why you can still pull and push is probably private/public keys authentication is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll preface with my answer with a reminder that it is impossible to recover a plaintext password from any system built with a modicum of security because passwords are hashed using a one-way function (e.g. SHA-512, bcrypt, etc).

To gain access to a Bitbucket repository you'll need to contact Bitbucket. If your former coworker was storing a repo in his personal account and not a company account then that's a silly mistake, but as you have a local repo you can just create a new Bitbucket or GitHub or VSTS account and push your local repo (Remember Git is decentralised).

Regarding your question about password recovery: The `.git` repository does not contain any user-secrets or authentication details besides a list of `remote` endpoint URIs which *may* have a username embedded in the URI.

If you're using Git over SSH then your computer will have SSH keys stored in your user profile or home directory somewhere (e.g. `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and a corresponding private key file somewhere). The private key file is typically encrypted with a local password (or DPAPI on Windows, e.g. https://blog.ropnop.com/extracting-ssh-private-keys-from-windows-10-ssh-agent/ ). If you're able to decrypt the private-key file then you'll retain the ability to communicate with the associated Git `remote` - provided the remote repo hasn't revoked your key's permissions already.

Comment: yes, I can push and pull data but I cant log in to bitbucket, If ever there's a way how to recover email address use, I can try to guest the password. I am hoping even the .git file don't store any password I think they store email use to this repo.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are authenticating with https or ssh. If you are using https you will be out of luck if you don't have the username and password. With ssh you will be able to copy the cert out of the .ssh folder in your user folder.